# Reading a text file (with filechooser) and storing into an ArrayList (each line is a new object inside arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, text, jfilechooser

Could someone help me input this data into 3 objects in an ArrayList (one for each player)?

Text file example:

```
 Steve| Barkley| 258| 300
 Carl |Johnson |142
 Frank|Davidson
```

Java code:

```
   //couldn't write the normal jfilechoose code above due to space
   File playerFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Scanner in = new Scanner(playerFile);

     String[] playerData; //array to hold data

     while (in.hasNext()) {
         String data = in.nextLine();

         playertData = data.split("\\|");
         playerData = Arrays.copyOf(playerData,playerData.length+1);

        String firstName = playerData[0];
        String lastName  = playerData[1];

      double playererayear1 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[2]==null?"0":playerData[2]);
        double playererayear2 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[3]==null?"0":playerData[3]);

        double playererayear3 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[4] == null?"0":playerData[4]);
```

Comment: what is studentdata here?

Comment: Ah i accidently changed the name to student while I was doing testruns but its still the playerData ill try to see if I can edit the question

Comment: Do you want to have an `ArrayList<Object[]>` or `ArrayList<Player>`?

Comment: ArrayList<Player> is better, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class for holding information about the Player.

```
public class Player {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double playerEraYear1;
  private double playerEraYear2;
  private double playerEraYear3;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public double getPlayerEraYear1() {
    return playerEraYear1;
  }

  public void setPlayerEraYear1(double playerEraYear1) {
    this.playerEraYear1 = playerEraYear1;
  }

  public double getPlayerEraYear2() {
    return playerEraYear2;
  }

  public void setPlayerEraYear2(double playerEraYear2) {
    this.playerEraYear2 = playerEraYear2;
  }

  public double getPlayerEraYear3() {
    return playerEraYear3;
  }

  public void setPlayerEraYear3(double playerEraYear3) {
    this.playerEraYear3 = playerEraYear3;
  }
}
```

Now you can parse the file, create a `Player` object for each of the players and add them to a list

```
public void parseFile() {
    File playerFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Scanner in = new Scanner(playerFile);
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
      String data = in.nextLine();
      String[] playerData = data.split("\\|");

      Player p = new Player();
      p.setFirstName(playerData[0]);
      p.setLastName(playerData[1]);

      if (playerData.size >= 3) {
        double playererayear1 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[2] == null ? "0" : playerData[2]);
        p.setPlayerEraYear1(playererayear1);
      }

      if (playerData.size >= 4) {
        double playererayear2 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[3] == null ? "0" : playerData[3]);
        p.setPlayerEraYear2(playererayear2);
      }

      if (playerData.size >= 5) {
        double playererayear3 = Double.parseDouble(playerData[4] == null ? "0" : playerData[4]);
        p.setPlayerEraYear3(playererayear3);
      }

      players.add(p);
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got: Selected file: C:\Users\yorkie\Documents\PlayerData.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at PlayerList.parseFile(PlayerList.java:44)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:6)

Comment: I means you dont have the last column in your text file. How many columns do you have in your text file for each player? Is it going to be 5?

Comment: If it is not going to be the same number of columns for each row you can add a check before setting the playerEraYear for years 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.aegle.validator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        File playerFile = new File("");//Set your file path
        Scanner in = new Scanner(playerFile);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String[] data = in.nextLine().split("\\|");
            Player player = new Player(data[0], data[1]);
            player.setYears(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 2, data.length));
            playerList.add(player);
        }

        System.out.println(playerList);//Just to test
    }
}

class Player {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String[] years;

    public Player(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setYears(String[] years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    //Introduce getters as you need

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", years=" + Arrays.toString(years) +
                '}';
    }
}
```